# ContentDocumentLink Trigger successfully blocks file upload on Org but fails in Dev Console

Tags: unit-test, before-trigger, contentversion, contentdocumentlink, fileupload

I want to block file uploads (ContentDocumentLink) on a FundingOpportunity object when status is Canceled or Closed. It works fine in the org, but it fails when I tried it on Dev console.
A File is still uploaded to a Closed or Cancelled FundingOpportunity

In my test class, the assertion fails because a ContentDocumentLink related to the FundingOpportunity is found. My assertion is that the size of the list should be 0.

Here is the code for the Trigger:

```
trigger ContentDocumentLinkTrigger on ContentDocumentLink (before insert) {
    System.debug('Called!');
    
   if(Trigger.isBefore){
       if(Trigger.isInsert){
           ContentDocumentLinkTriggerHandler.onBeforeInsert(Trigger.new);
       }
     
   }        
}
```

ContentDocumentLinkTriggerHandler

```
public class ContentDocumentLinkTriggerHandler {
    public static String getRelatedDocumentType(ID relatedDocId){
        return relatedDocId.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName();
        
    }
    public static void solicitationFile(Id solicitationId){
        List<FundingOpportunity> parentCase = [SELECT Id, Status FROM FundingOpportunity WHERE ID =: solicitationId];
        
        for(FundingOpportunity c: parentCase){                
            if (c.Status == 'Closed' || c.Status == 'Canceled' || c.Status == 'Cancelled'){
                System.debug('Cant upload files for Canceled or Closed');
                c.addError('You cant upload files');                          
            }   
        }
    }
    public static void onBeforeInsert(List<ContentDocumentLink> cdls){
        System.debug('In handler class');
        for (ContentDocumentLink cdl : cdls) {
            String relatedDocType =  getRelatedDocumentType(cdl.LinkedEntityId);   
            if(relatedDocType == 'FundingOpportunity'){
                solicitationFile(cdl.LinkedEntityId);
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

My test class ContentDocumentLinkHandlerTest

```
@isTest(seeAllData=false)
public class ContentDocumentLinkTriggerHandlerTest {
    @testSetup
    static void setUp(){
            FundingOpportunity sol = new FundingOpportunity(
            name = 'testSol',
            status = 'Closed'
        );
        insert sol;
        
    }
    @isTest
    static void onBeforeInsertTest(){
        
        
        ContentVersion conVer = new ContentVersion(
            title = 'Test',
            pathOnClient = 'test.doc',
            versionData = Blob.valueOf('Test Content'),
            isMajorVersion = true
        );
        insert conVer;
        FundingOpportunity sol = [SELECT Id, Status FROM FundingOpportunity];
        System.debug(sol);
        List<ContentDocument> docs = [SELECT Id, Title, LatestPublishedVersionId FROM ContentDocument WHERE Title =:'Test'];
        ContentDocumentLink conLink = new ContentDocumentLink(
            linkedEntityId = sol.Id,
            contentDocumentId = docs[0].Id,
            shareType = 'V'
        );
        
        System.Test.startTest();
        insert conLink;
        System.Test.stopTest();
        
        List<ContentDocumentLink> solFile = [SELECT Id, LinkedEntityId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId =: sol.Id];
        
        System.debug(sol.Id);
        System.debug(solFile);

        System.assertEquals(0, solFile.size());
        
        

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to recreate your issue in a sandbox but was unable to resolve it while keeping `addError()`. `addError()` was not throwing an exception in the unit test. Maybe someone else can recommend how to solve that issue.

To get it working, you could throw an exception rather than using `addError()`. `addError()` is great (especially for field-level errors) since it processes everything before throwing an exception, but that functionality doesn't seem needed in the context of the file upload screen within Salesforce.

Add an exception class to your handler -

```
class ContentDocumentLinkTriggerHandlerException extends Exception { }
```

Replace your addError() with a throw -

```
if (c.Status == 'Closed' || c.Status == 'Canceled' || c.Status == 'Cancelled'){          
      throw new ContentDocumentLinkTriggerHandlerException('You cant upload files');                          
}
```

Update your unit test to ensure the exception is being thrown -

```
Exception caughtError = null;
        
System.Test.startTest();
try {
    insert conLink;
} catch (Exception error) {
   caughtError = error;
}
System.Test.stopTest();
        
Assert.isNotNull(caughtError);
```

Comment: Hi Wes, turns out the Exception was the exact thing I was looking for. I didn't need addError() after all. I managed to make it work. Thanks!